# Gather Error Message Documentation into a list

Tags: docfx

I have error messages scattered around the code and would like to gather them into one section of the output documentation.

File 1:

```
// E00123 File not found /usr/bin/local/myfile/YourProject
// To resolve this error look in /usr/bin/local for your specific project.
// This can be caused if the plugin is not installed.
Console.WriteLn("E00129 File not found {myfile}");
```

File 2:

```
// E00227 User not authorized: {username}
// Contact your system administrator to get access to the resource.
Console.WriteLn("E00227 User not authorized {username}");
```

Then generate a page in the docfx documentation where those are automatically consolidated:

```
Error:

E00123 File not found /usr/bin/local/myfile/YourProject
  To resolve this error look in /usr/bin/local for your specific project.
  This can be caused if the plugin is not installed.

E00227 User not authorized: {username}
  Contact your system administrator to get access to the resource.
```

What are some tips for making that happen.  What keywords can I search for in docfx to be able to find that information.